# Select the row TH of related TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/wT3Ev/
How do i retrieve the text that is in the row TH of the selected td?

Yes i found some related posts, but nothing that does the trick for me.

I tried:

```
$(document).on("click", "#sTab td,#pvTab td", function () {
alert($('#sTab tr').find('th:nth-child(' + $(this).parent().index() + ')').innerHTML);

alert($(this).parent());

var th = $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq( this.cellIndex );   

alert(th.innerHTML); 
}
```

Comment: *SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.*

Comment: `alert($(this).closest('tr').find('th').text() );` http://jsfiddle.net/T4tua/

Comment: That's an overly-complex demo. You want to click a `td` (*any* `td`?) and retrieve the text from the `th` at the beginning of the clicked-row?

Comment: Yes, any td, and yes.

Comment: Why is the first row not in a thead? The Tidy button also does wonders in the fiddle. You could simplify it by listening for a click on a tr and finding the th.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
/* binds a click-handler to the 'tbody' element,
   filters those clicks to only those that originate on a 'td' element:
*/
$('tbody').on('click', 'td', function(){
    /* gets the siblings of the clicked 'td' element, filters those siblings
       for 'th' elements, gets the first of those matching elements,
       and then retrieves the text of that element, assigning it to the variable:
    */
    var thText = $(this).siblings('th').first().text();
    console.log(thText);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wT3Ev/7/).

Or, using a little more DOM (a tiny, *tiny* efficiency increase):

```
// same as above:
$('tbody').on('click', 'td', function(){
    /* using DOM (not jQuery), moving from the clicked 'td' element
       to its parentNode ('tr'), retrieving the first of its children
       (JavaScript is zero-indexed, the first child is at position '0'),
       and retrieving its textContent (the text of the 'th'):
    */
    var thText = this.parentNode.children[0].textContent;
    console.log(thText);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wT3Ev/9/).

References:

- [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Sure, I'll add explanations to the answer (in comments to the code).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var index = $(this).index();
console.log($(this).parents("table").find("th:eq(" + index + ")").text());
```

Edit: **row** header: `console.log($(this).closest("tr").find("th").text());`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wT3Ev/4/

Answer (score 1):

You weren't too far off. This works with your example:

```
$(document).on("click", "#sTab td,#pvTab td", function () {
    var tdIndex = $(this).index(),
        table = $(this).closest('table'),
        headingIndex = tdIndex + 1,
        thText = table.find('th:nth-child(' + headingIndex + ')').text();
    alert(thText);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent().find('th').html();
```

edit: explanation - row is always cell's parent so no need to look for index - just look for header in the row where you have the cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/qA6R9/